# Azure AD different number of client and server claims

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory

We need to integrate AzureAD authentication flow into our existing project. So I found the sample code available at [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity) . It basically contains two web projects. A MVC project as Client and Web API as Server.

We though of using "upn" claim from JWT token to uniquely identify the logged in user. I ran the sample code and was able to authenticate the user in Azure AD. When i inspect the Access token i got from AAD at jwt.io the claims section doesn't contain the "upn" but i was able to retrieve the "upn" on the client using `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn)`. Added this access token as bearer authorization header and made a call to web api. Here I am not able to retrive the "upn" claim using `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn)`. The value is null for this claim. Do i need to do any additional configuration to get on server side. As of now I am able to retrieve upn only on the client side.

Comment: You need to show how you have configured authentication on the API side. Is the access token you fetched meant for the API? (i.e. is its audience claim set to the app id URI of the API)

Comment: @juunas Yes the the Audience value is the AppID URI of the API. As I said Its a sample project downloaded from Git. I just changed the web.config values for Audience and TenantID keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example project in question:

> calls a web API under the application's identity, instead of the user's identity

At line 95 of TodoListController it gets the token with:

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
```

It is calling the API as itself, so it is an app-only call, not a delegated call. Thus there is no UPN. You would find an *appid* claim though that identifies the calling app.

Check this other example that makes delegated calls to the API: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

As you can see there the call acquiring the token is quite different:

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(todoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Note that the authentication configuration is also different: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs.

Comment: Thank you. Will let you know if it is working or not.

Comment: Able to get UPN in token now. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Just remember that now the client gets the token *silently* instead of a call to the token endpoint. This will fail if it doesn't find the token in the cache. The `NaiveSessionCache` class that it uses simply stores the tokens in the session. And the session is in memory by default. So if your server restarts for any reason, the user will need to be redirected again to Azure AD to get new tokens in the cache. If you want a more robust solution, you'll have to replace the cache class with e.g. DB storage.